# Effect of smoking cigarettes on performance at the gym

Tags: muscle, workout, health, muscle-recovery, smoking

What, biologically, is different on a day you smoke cigarettes and then hit the gym?

Comment: Given nicotine's relatively short biological half life, it's going to depend a lot on how long before the workout, so you may want to specify.

Comment: Along with the above i would also specify that it would also depend in the fitness regime you are following.

Comment: What are you doing "in the gym" ?

Comment: Provide more details: cardio? Weightlifting? Effects of smoking on general performance?